# Zonal statistics as table fails using Geoprocessor and C#

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, geoprocessing, zonal-statistics

[image]

The above code snippets fails while calculating the Zonal statistics as table using Geo processor in C#, butit works in ArcMap. Any ideas where/what I did wrong?

Comment: Have you got your spatial analyst extension checked out? BTW when including a snippet it's best to also include it as formatted text, it's far easier to read and copy to modify. Consider putting it into a try/catch and see if there's more detail in the thrown exception.

Comment: Also when pasting the actual code, the search engines can index it so people can find this question again by searching on keywords like `ZonalStatisticsAsTable`

Comment: Thanks Michael Miles-Stimson..I checked  out the spatial extension and give full path to the output table then it works.